# Javascript code of an HTML file calling jQuery on an external HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an HTML file which runs a javascript code doing, among other things, also some jQuery calls. I would like to separate a portion of my HTML code in an external file because I would like to use it as a common file among several HTML files and I would like the javascript code to be able to do the jQuery calls also to the external file. Any suggestion on this? I am quite new to javascript, thus any kind of suggestion on how to proceed would be very helpful.

Here is an example showing my problem. Note that in the HTML code I indicated the portion I would like to separate.

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MWE</title>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="js/init.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><a class="mobileUI-site-name">My website</a></h1>
    <!-- PORTION TO EXTRACT: begin
    <nav id="nav" class="mobileUI-site-nav">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Three</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    PORTION TO EXTRACT: end -->
    <div> Some text here </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript** (just the portion of interest)

```
var x = jQuery('.mobileUI-site-name'), site_name = (x.length > 0 ? x.html() : ''),
    site_nav_options = new Array();

jQuery('.mobileUI-site-nav a').each(function() {
    var t = jQuery(this), indent;
    indent = Math.max(0,t.parents('li').length - 1);
    site_nav_options.push(
    '<div class="mobileUI-site-nav-link><span class="indent-' + indent + '"></span>' + t.text() + '</div>'
    );
});
```

For the HTML code I should simply include in the head

```
<script>
   $(function(){
      $("#top-menu").load("./common/menu.html");
   });
</script>
```

and the proper `<div id="top-menu"></div>` in the body. How should I change the javascript code?

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be helpful:
[Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file) .
It explains how to import HTML into existing HTML using JQuery. Specifically

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

where the content you want to extract would need to be put into "b.html".
To access the added HTML you would need to use a callback, as described here:
https://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$("#includedContent").load("b.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

I.e. replace the alert command with whatever you want to do with JQuery that affects the loaded HTML.

Comment: I tried what you say and in the load function I can do my javascript code. My problem is the following: the portion of javascript I posted is part of an init.js script loaded in the HTML head. Even moving the portion of javascript code in the load function as you suggest, I anyway need the variables site_name and site_nav_options in the script init.js for other things. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could create a function in `init.js`, which does whatever you need, which is then called in the `load`-callback. You can then for example pass `site_nav_options` as parameters to this function. Does this fit to what you need?